# Creating New Dataframe Based on Cells of Other Dataframes using For loop R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have 2 data frames with the same row and column structure that both have a lot of NA values.  I want to create another data frame that simply tells me which cells in the 2 original data frames actually have values.  For example

[image]
So far I have been able to do this manually by mutating a series of if else statements for each column like this:

```
combined <- trial_1[,1:2] %>%
   mutate("Part1" = ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part1) & !is.na(trial_2$Part1), "1 & 2",
 ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part1) & is.na(trial_2$Part1), "1 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part1) & !is.na(trial_2$Part1),
 "2 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part1) & is.na(trial_2$Part1),
 "NA", "Failed"))))) %>%

   mutate("Part2" = ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part2) & !is.na(trial_2$Part2),
 "1 & 2",ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part2) & is.na(trial_2$Part2), "1 only",
 ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part2) & !is.na(trial_2$Part2), "2 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part2) & is.na(trial_2$Part2), "NA", "Failed"))))) %>%

   mutate("Part3" = ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part3) & !is.na(trial_2$Part3), "1 & 2",
 ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part3) & is.na(trial_2$Part3),
 "1 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part3) & !is.na(trial_2$Part3), "2 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part3) & is.na(trial_2$Part3),
 "NA", "Failed"))))) %>%

   mutate("Part4" = ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part4) & !is.na(trial_2$Part4),
 "1 & 2", ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$Part4) & is.na(trial_2$Part4), "1 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part4) & !is.na(trial_2$Part4),
 "2 only", ifelse(is.na(trial_1$Part4) & is.na(trial_2$Part4), "NA", "Failed")))))
```

But this is obviously not efficient so I tried using a for loop, which does not work:

```
participants <- list('Part1', 'Part2', 'Part3', 'Part4')

combined <- trial_1[,1:2]

for (i in participants) {

combined <- combined %>%
  mutate(i = ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$i) & !is.na(trial_2$i), "1 & 2",
 ifelse(!is.na(trial_1$i) & is.na(trial_2$i), "1 only",
 ifelse(is.na(trial_1$i) & !is.na(trial_2$i), "2 only",
 ifelse(is.na(trial_1$i) & is.na(trial_2$i), "NA", "Failed")))))

}
```

Any help on how to restructure this for loop, which I think is the way to go, would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to try using `tidyverse`. First, merge the two data frames together with a join, based on `number` and `status`. You can indicate the trial number here if you'd like.

Then, you can put your data into long form, and look at each element in `Part` individually. With `mutate` create a new string based on which trials have non-missing values.

Finally, use `pivot_wider` to put the data into wide form.

```
library(tidyverse)

trial_1 %>%
  left_join(trial_2, by = c("number", "status"), suffix = c(".t1", ".t2")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Part"), names_to = c("Part", ".value"), names_pattern = "Part(\\d+).(t[1-9])") %>%
  mutate(part_string = case_when(
    !is.na(t1) & !is.na(t2) ~ "1 & 2",
    !is.na(t1) ~ "1 only",
    !is.na(t2) ~ "2 only",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(number, status), names_from = "Part", values_from = "part_string", names_prefix = "Part")
```

**Output**

```
  number status    Part1  Part2  Part3  Part4
   <int> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1      1 very low  1 only NA     2 only NA   
2      2 low       NA     1 only 1 & 2  NA   
3      3 medium    2 only NA     1 only NA   
4      4 high      NA     NA     NA     NA   
5      5 very high NA     NA     1 only 1 & 2
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Ben!  Problem solved.  Guess a for loop was not the way to go.